# TestNG: gigantic collections as test parameters ruins output

Tags: java, testng

The problem is simple: TestNG sends all the toString() outputs of objects sent by the DataProvider method to the Test method. This can cause gigantic outputs, like test reports, TestNG plugin output, etc, making them unreadable, or even crash Firefox.

The question: can I configure TestNG, so it won't toString() everything to my face? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide signature for the test method that receives input from DataProvider?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here with your toString() remark, can you be more specific?

Comment: Test method: public void testLoc(final String category, final Properties refLangProp, final Properties langProp). The two Properties instance can be very large (okay, not millions, but thousands of key-value pairs). toString() was just my idea what is happening, all I see that TestNG eclipse plugin messes the console output AND the results tab with the contents of these collections, and this is true for the html output, too. I want to ignore these info, because its useless, and claims much space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some investigation and I'm quite sure the toString() is called on every parameter that is passed by the data provider to the test method. So you shouldn't pass collections or you have to override their toString().